# VBA to replace the same letter with different values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write vba code that will look up a letter in a string and replace it with a specific cell value.

Problem is that the letter may appear in the string a maximum of 3 times and each time the letter needs to be replaced by different value.

Example string `I have x and x and x`

The first x should be replaced with 1, second with 2 and third with 3.

My code so far

```
for i = 0 to lim

range("B" & lim +13).Value = replace (range("B" & lim +13), "x",range("K" & lim +13).Value)

Next i
```

The problem with above code is that this will replace each `x` with the same value; I would like to make it with a specific order of replacement.

Ideally the second and third replace would come from a different cell value of my choice.

Comment: What form(s) does "x" take in reality?

Comment: x will be replace by numeric values.

Comment: Can you post snapshots of some examples on the worksheet itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the split function:

```
Sub XTest()
Dim s As String
s = "I have x and x and x"
Dim parts As Variant
parts = Split(s, "x")
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(parts) - 1
    parts(i) = parts(i) & i + 1
Next i
s = Join(parts, "")
Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use `Replace()` function:

```
Dim s As String
Dim i As Long

s = "I have x and x and x"
Do While InStr(s, "x") > 0
    i = i + 1
    s = Replace(s, "x", i, , 1)
Loop
```

so you may wrap it in a function
:

```
Function Rep(s As String, x as string) As String
    Dim i As Long

    Do While InStr(s, x) > 0
        i = i + 1
        s = Replace(s, x, i, , 1)
    Loop
    Rep = s
End Function
```

to be used like:

```
range("B" & lim +13).Value = Rep(range("B" & lim +13).Value, "x")
```

Comment: Nice solution HTH.

Comment: Your approach in using a Do loop is simple, clean, and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Put you replacements in order in an array then for each cell replace the 1st "x" with the 1st array value, the 2nd with the 2nd array value and so on.

```
Dim newString As String, i As Long, j As Long, replacements As Variant

For i = 0 To lim

    replacements = Array(1, 2, "some other value or cell", "4th replacement")

    newString = Range("B" & i + 13).value

    For j = 0 To UBound(replacements)
        If InStr(newString, "x") = 0 Then Exit For
        newString = Replace$(newString, "x", replacements(j), 1, 1)
    Next

    Range("B" & i + 13).value = newString

Next
```

(I used `i` in the `Range` insetad of `lim` as `lim` never changes in your for loop)